# ST_Slope using scale argument

Tags: postgis

I am trying to calculate slope from an elevation raster that is in degrees (lat/lon). The elevation is in meters.

The `ST_Slope()` function in PostGIS seems ideal for this purpose. However, I'm confused by the `scale` argument, which gives the ratio of vertical to horizontal units. The [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Slope.html) suggest using `scale=111120`. But wouldn't the scale vary based on latitude? How does a fixed `scale` argument give accurate results, as opposed to projecting the raster into meters?

Edit: Based on the comment by @user30184, what is the best way to calculate accurate slope? Raster reprojection is tricky - is there a way to avoid this? Is there a formula to adjust the slope based on the latitude of each tile?

Comment: You are right, 111120 is just a rough estimate for getting a result that looks about reasonable. Don't use it for real work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for how to get an accurate result? See the edit to the question.

Comment: Well, *"a rough estimate"* is only roughly what it is; the (averaged ellipsoidal axis -> sphere) surface distance in *meter*, corresponding to 1 degree of latitude on the sphere, and 1 degree of longitude *at the equator*. So, on the y-axis, this scale factor is a constant - if you scale it based on the latitude, the latitudial value get's mis-scaled. That being said, you could approximate with sth. like `0.5 * (111120 + cos(<lat_tile_center>) * 111120)` to scale based on the average between the scaled longitudinal distance and the latitudinal constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @geozelot for the tip on adjusting the scale factor. It replaces the constant of 111120 with `(0.5 * (111120 + cosd(ST_UpperLeftY(t1.rast)-ST_Height(t1.rast)/2*ST_PixelHeight(t1.rast)) * 111120))`, using the latitude of the raster tile center.

Here's the query that works:

```
SELECT t1.rid, 
  ST_Slope(ST_Union(t2.rast), 1, t1.rast, '32BF' , 'PERCENT',
     (0.5 * (111120 + cosd(ST_UpperLeftY(t1.rast)-
     ST_Height(t1.rast)/2*ST_PixelHeight(t1.rast)) * 111120))
     ,false) AS slope
FROM elevation t1
CROSS JOIN elevation t2
WHERE ST_Intersects(t1.rast,t2.rast)
GROUP BY t1.rid, t1.rast;
```